# Unable to connect using hostname read from a file in paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to connect to a list of nodes (hostnames) using paramiko and I'm getting a socket.gaierror when trying to connect. It's reading the hostnames from a file but when it tries to connect I get a gaierror.

```
import paramiko
import socket

f = open('<filename>', 'r')

 for node in f.readlines():
    try:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        print('Connecting to %s.' % node)
        node.strip()
        ssh.connect(node, username=user,password=passw)
        print('Connected to %s.' % node)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        ssh.close()

    except socket.gaierror:
        print('Unable to connect to %s.' % node)
        pass
```

The file with the hostnames in it just has them listed with one hostname per line. For example:

*hostname1

hostname2

hostname3

ect...*

However if I take the code out of the for loop and just assign the host name to a variable then it works.

```
import paramiko
import socket

node = '<hostname>'

try:
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    print('Connecting to %s.' % node)
    node.strip()
    ssh.connect(node, username=user,password=passw)
    print('Connected to %s.' % node)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    ssh.close()

except socket.gaierror:
    print('Unable to connect to %s.' % node)
    pass
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening the file with [universal newline support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) ('`rU`') to ensure it's not picking up carriage returns.

**Edit:** Also, add your `node.strip()` as an argument to the `ssh.connect()` call.  The `strip()` call is not in-place.  I've edited the code example to reflect this:

```
import paramiko
import socket

with open('<filename>', 'rU') as f:

    for node in f.readlines():
        try:
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.load_system_host_keys()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            print('Connecting to %s.' % node)
            ssh.connect(node.strip(), username=user,password=passw)
            print('Connected to %s.' % node)
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
            ssh.close()

        except socket.gaierror:
            print('Unable to connect to %s.' % node)
            pass
```

Comment: After trying that it's still coming back with a gaierror.

Comment: See my edit about `node.strip()` and give that a try.